# jQGrid asp.net mvc 3 implementation from scratch

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am trying to implement `jQGrid` in my application with some basic features including filtering and sub grid. I looked numerous articles but many of them seem to be old and outdated. I think i am struggling with the basics of implementing it. I will really appreciate if you can provide basic controller view structure or refer to any sort of tutorial from scratch with `asp. net mvc 3.`

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: If you gave a better understanding of what you wanted to accomplish with jQuery it'd be easier to offer an example.

Comment: I think you misread the problem. It's not jQuery, its jQGrid.

Comment: Oh I have a sample for that... hold on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code in the View (first mark-up, then JS):

```
@model SampleApp.SampleModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Stackoverflow Title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_defaultLayout.cshtml";

}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/grid/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/grid/grid.locale-en.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/grid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myJSHelper.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="loadGridResultsScript1">
    // This code LOADs the grid by calling the MVC Action to get Data
    $(document).ready(function () { helper.loadSearchResults('@Model.JobCode'); });
</script>

<!-- these are the jQuery Grid controls -->
<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

Here is the JS function from myHelper JS file:

```
loadSearchResults: function (id) {

        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: vpath + '/Sample/GetTargets/' + id,
            datatype: 'json', mtype: 'POST', colNames: cols,
            colModel: colModel, pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum: 15, rowList: [5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100], sortname: cols[1],
            sortorder: "asc", viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '', caption: ' '
        });
        $("#list").setGridWidth(1000, true);
        $("#list").setGridHeight(350, true);


    }
```

and here is the Action that jQuery calls:

```
        public ActionResult GetTargets(string id, string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {

        var repo = IOCContainer.Resolve<DataRepository>();
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var job = svc.GetJobByCode(id);
        // job is my 'Model', it is a System.Data.DataSet

        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;

        int totalRecords = (job.Targets == null) ? 0 : job.Tables[0].Rows.Count; 
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
        List<DataRow> pageSet = Enumerable.Empty<DataRow>().ToList();

        if (totalRecords > 0)
        {
            // Get rows for current page!!!
            if (sord == "asc")
            {
                if (sidx == "   ") sidx = job.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName;

                pageSet = job.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                        .OrderBy(q => q[sidx])
                        .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                        .Take(pageSize)
                        .ToList();
            }
            else
                pageSet = job.Targets.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                        .OrderBy(q => q[sidx])
                        .Reverse()
                        .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                        .Take(pageSize)
                        .ToList();
        }

        var cols = GetColumnNames(job.Tables[0]);
        // Func to get Cells, called later on in code...
        Func<DataRow, string[], string[]> getCells = (pkg, columns) =>
        {
            var cellList = new List<string>();
            cellList.Add(pkg[0].ToString());
            foreach (var col in columns)
            {
                if (col.StartsWith("_")) continue;
                object cellContent = pkg[col];
                string cellText = string.Empty;
                if (cellContent is DateTime)
                {
                    cellText = ((DateTime)cellContent).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                }
                else if (cellContent is decimal || cellContent is double)
                {
                    cellText = string.Format("{0:c}", cellContent);
                }
                else
                {
                    cellText = String.Format("{0}", cellContent);
                }
                cellList.Add(cellText);
            }

            return cellList.ToArray();
        };
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
                from item in pageSet
                select new
                {
                    i = item[0].ToString(),
                    cell = getCells(item, cols)
                }).ToArray()
        };
        return Json(jsonData);
    }
```

I hope you find this helpful.  Let me know if there are any questions