# Rendering json data into a grid in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am looking to populate my grid with JSON data. The data is in the below format:

```
[{
  "SiteId":"1",
  "SiteName":"University of Minessota",
  "SiteStatus":"Fully Operational"
},{
  "SiteId":"2",
  "SiteName":"MSP Airport-Humphrey",
  "SiteStatus":"Settlement Required"
},{
  "SiteId":"3",
  "SiteName":"City Of Minneapolis-Lot C",
  "SiteStatus":"Fully Operational"
},{
  "SiteId":"4",
  "SiteName":"TargetCenter",
  "SiteStatus":"Low Tickets"
},{
  "SiteId":"5",
  "SiteName":"Excel Energy Center",
  "SiteStatus":"Out Of Tickets"
}]
```

and i am passing this to the view using my controller method:

```
public JsonResult StatusReport()
{
    List<CenterStatus> status = MvcList.Models.CenterStatus.GetStatus();
    return this.Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now in my view I need to populate this JSON data into a grid:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "CenterStatus/StatusReport.aspx",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                $("#GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].siteID + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].siteName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].siteStatus + "</td></tr>");    
            }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

But I have no luck in achieving my goal so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: Inspect your response with one of the http tracing tools(Fidder, firebug etc.) and check your response. So you can tell us if it is a server side issue or a client side issue.

Comment: have you used jQuery Grid? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491459/jqgrid-asp-net-mvc-3-implementation-from-scratch/11491885#11491885

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this. do not call `append` in a loop. Set it to a variable and call the `html` function only once.

```
success: function (data) {
                            var row=""
                            $.each(data,function(index,item){
                                row+="<tr><td>"+item.SiteName+"</td></tr>";
                            });
                            $("#GridView1").html(row);
                       },
```

Working sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/x76LD/1/

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use just `data` instead of `data.d` in your success function.

Comment: I agree.  I've never had any issues using data (as opposed to data.d) with > ASP.Net MVC 1.  Easy to do a console.log(data) in the Success to see the structure of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `url: "CenterStatus/StatusReport.aspx",` might have something to do with it. The correct url should probably be:

`url: "/CenterStatus/StatusReport"`